# how to get rid of the resent year from input type="month" and only display the current year up to new year?

Tags: html

```html
<div class="input-group input-daterange">
     <input type="month" class="form-control"  name="current">
     <div class="input-group-addon">to</div>
     <input type="month" class="form-control" name="new">
     <div id="school_validation"></div>
</div>
```

### Questions,

**how will I get rid of the years that has been past already and only display the current year up to new year.**

Answer (score 1):

To set a minimum date in any input date you can use the property "min" and to set the maximum date use "max"
example:

```
<input type="date" min="2020-01-01" max="2021-01-01" value="2020-01-01">
```

This will set the min date and maximum date.

and to set the current date value for the said input, you need javascript for that or you can set it by hand using the "value" property.

Also, there is no input type "month" you have to use type "date" for that

Comment: anyways already red about this article and it solves my problem https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/month btw still thank you for your response and to correct you there's a input type month.

Comment: I did check again and yes it does exist. sorry about that. thanks too for correcting my mistake statment :)